# Trying to get docker to run, constantly gives me an error

Tags: bash, apache, docker

I am trying to run docker with `docker-compose up`, but I continue to get this error.

```
Removing storemagento_nginx_1
storemagento_redis_1 is up-to-date
storemagento_db_1 is up-to-date
storemagento_fpm_1 is up-to-date
Recreating f751fff8304c_f751fff8304c_f751fff8304c_f751fff8304c_f751fff8304c_f751fff8304c_f751fff8304c_f751fff8304c_f751fff8304c_f751fff8304c_f751fff8304c_f751fff8304c_f751fff8304c_f751fff8304c_f751fff8304c_f751fff8304c_f751fff8304c_f751fff8304c_storemagento_nginx_1 ... 
Recreating f751fff8304c_f751fff8304c_f751fff8304c_f751fff8304c_f751fff8304c_f751fff8304c_f751fff8304c_f751fff8304c_f751fff8304c_f751fff8304c_f751fff8304c_f751fff8304c_f751fff8304c_f751fff8304c_f751fff8304c_f751fff8304c_f751fff8304c_f751fff8304c_storemagento_nginx_1 ... error

ERROR: for f751fff8304c_f751fff8304c_f751fff8304c_f751fff8304c_f751fff8304c_f751fff8304c_f751fff8304c_f751fff8304c_f751fff8304c_f751fff8304c_f751fff8304c_f751fff8304c_f751fff8304c_f751fff8304c_f751fff8304c_f751fff8304c_f751fff8304c_f751fff8304c_storemagento_nginx_1  Cannot start service nginx: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint storemagento_nginx_1 (7b1963dbb7e3b5ea97394dce65168d4a591301fb834c489aad52a9c2ea4e6eb7): Error starting userland proxy: Bind for 0.0.0.0:80: unexpected error (Failure EADDRINUSE)

ERROR: for nginx  Cannot start service nginx: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint storemagento_nginx_1 (7b1963dbb7e3b5ea97394dce65168d4a591301fb834c489aad52a9c2ea4e6eb7): Error starting userland proxy: Bind for 0.0.0.0:80: unexpected error (Failure EADDRINUSE)
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

This used to work fine, but then I installed an updated version of apache through brew and now this happens every time I switch back and forth. I used to be able to try and kill all of the apache processes or restart and that seemed to work. However now I can not get port 80 to free up. If I kill all processes running on port 80 apache will go away for a minute, but then return again.

So when I run

```
sudo lsof -i :80 | grep LISTEN
httpd   27987 root    4u  IPv6 0xcfcc888f0ccae989      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd   27992 _www    4u  IPv6 0xcfcc888f0ccae989      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
```

These processes continue to return. I was trying to create an alias that I could use to kill the processes correctly as below. But I can not get this working in terminal.

```
alias stopall-port80="sudo kill -9 $(sudo lsof -i :80 | grep LISTEN | egrep -v 'PID' | awk '{print $2}' | sort -n | uniq)"
```

If I take just the section `sudo lsof -i :80 | grep LISTEN | egrep -v 'PID' | awk '{print $2}' | sort -n | uniq` and put it in the terminal it produces the correct PID's as expected. However when I try to run the alias `stopall-port80` I get `bash: 27057: command not found`.

UPDATE

This is working instead of using the alias

```
stopall_port80() {
    sudo kill -9 $(sudo lsof -i :80 | grep LISTEN | egrep -v 'PID' | awk '{print $2}' | sort -n | uniq);
}
```

Comment: This kind of approach is a code smell -- meaning it indicates that you're using the wrong tool the job. If your web server were running under a proper process supervision system, then the Right Thing would be to tell that supervision system to shut it down or restart it. That's a lot more reliable, lower-overhead and less race-prone than a big hairy pipeline.

Comment: ...so, if this is MacOS, you should ideally be running your webserver under launchd, meaning that `launchctl` can be used to start or stop it.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I agree, however, I already have done `sudo apachectl stop` and I know apache is not running. However, when I view the processes I see 2 apache processes running. If I kill those and then continue checking the processes, they come back after a few minutes with me doing nothing. It should be noted that I installed apache through brew, but the default apache is still on my system as well and they may be coliding somehow.

Comment: then it probably **is** a launchd job that's configured to restart Apache after it's been shut down. If you want it to stay down, you should tell launchctl so, instead of fighting it by shutting the job down yourself, after which it sees that as an error and starts it back up.

Comment: Can you add that function here again since the other poster deleted that answer?

Comment: I'd rather not. Why don't you [edit] to show how you tried to use a function and how that attempt failed? That way I can address the details of what went wrong.

Comment: And to investigate towards why you're seeing the service restart -- can you see if `sudo launchctl list | egrep 'http|apache'` returns anything?

Comment: (I'm on the other side of the MacPorts-vs-Homebrew divide, which makes it a little harder to investigate what their packaging does in practice).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy It returns `27987 -9 org.apache.httpd`

Comment: Uhh, `launchctl stop` with no arguments? It needs a name of *what* it should be stopping to do anything.

Comment: So, that's saying that launchd was running httpd, and that process was terminated by a SIGKILL (which makes sense, since that's what you just recently did).

Comment: It's not `launchctl stop httpd` but `launchctl stop org.apache.httpd`. And even that is just telling it to shut down, not to *stay* down. To tell it to *stay* down you'd want `unload`, potentially with the `-w` argument if you want that to persist through a reboot.

Comment: Ill edit my question.

Comment: On OSX `netstat` is available as `/usr/sbin/netstat`

Comment: BTW -- if you want to answer your own question, use the "Add an Answer" button, vs editing that answer into the question; that way the answer can be commented on, voted on, &c. separately from the question itself (as opposed to being in the question and having effectively privileged status).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Issue 1: Unwanted Apache Restarts

If the port frees up "for a minute" and then is in use again, you should tell the process supervision system that's starting the conflicting process *to stop running that process*. In the case of Apache httpd on MacOS, that looks like:

```
sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist
```

---

#### Issue 2: Surprising alias expansion

Your original code was -- on account of the use of double quotes -- building the list of httpd processes *at the time when your alias was defined*, not at the time when your alias was *executed*. You could fix that by changing the quoting type, but the better answer is to use a function:

```
stopall_port80() { sudo kill $(...); }
```

...which will evaluate the `$(...)` when the function is run, not when it's set up in your `.bashrc`.

---

#### Issue 3: Detecting PIDs Using A Port On MacOS

```
sudo lsof -n -iTCP:80 | awk '/LISTEN/ { print $2 }'
```

Comment: When I run the first command I get `/path/to/current/folder/org.apache.httpd: No such file or directory`. Where does this need to be run? Also, on the second part, I tried moving it inside a function like that but I was also getting an error on that.

Comment: Okay I was able to get the function working. I could not have the "80" in the function name. Thanks for that!

Comment: Sorry -- that's `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist`

Comment: the `80` is legal (except at the beginning of the name), the `-` is not (some versions of bash allow it anyhow, but not all). `stopall_port80() { echo "This works"; }` is fine.

Comment: That did it! Thanks Charles!